# Counting frequency of specific dataframe cells

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to count the specific number of times a number is seen within a specific cell.

DataFrame ScreenShot

[image: img1]

The values are between 1 to 7.

In this column `Entity_Types`, the first occurrence has     `7,7,6,7,6,7,1,7,7,7,2`. I think I need to create 7 additional empty columns and count the frequency of each occurrence(for each number) and append them to a new column labeled `Entity_Types_1`,`Entity_Types_2`...etc.

Example: New column 7 would have each count of 7 while New Column 1 would have the count of all 1's in that respective cell. I have a table that has 30,000 rows so I was wondering how to run it in a loop to fill out the rest of the dataset.

I can easily do it in excel using this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(O2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(O2,"2","")))
```

Where O2 is `Entity_Types` and "2" = the number we are looking to find.

End Example

[image: img2]

Comment: Please post data and not pictures of data.  Also, what have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Entity_Types` is a column of strings in you data frame `df`.  If that is the case, you can use:

```
for i in range(8):
    df['Entity_Types_{}'.format(i)] = df.Entity_Types.str.count(str(i))
```